# In VS Code I get TypeScript Server Error (4.8.4) Debug Failure when using Quick Fix: Install all missing types packages

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

After turning on `noImplicitAny: true` in TS project some of my imports are highlighted with error:

```
Could not find a declaration file for module X. X implicitly has an 'any' type.
```

When I View Problem then VS Code suggests to use `Quick Fix: Install all missing types packages` in order to fix errors.

However, that gives following error:

```
<semantic> TypeScript Server Error (4.8.4)
Debug Failure. False expression.
Error: Debug Failure. False expression.
    at NodeTypingsInstaller.installPackage (/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/extensions/node_modules/typescript/lib/tsserver.js:184082:30)
    at TypingsCache.installPackage (/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/extensions/node_modules/typescript/lib/tsserver.js:171393:39)
    at Project.installPackage (/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/extensions/node_modules/typescript/lib/tsserver.js:171680:42)
    at applySingleCodeActionCommand (/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/extensions/node_modules/typescript/lib/tsserver.js:167662:24)
    at Object.applyCodeActionCommand (/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/extensions/node_modules/typescript/lib/tsserver.js:167656:125)
    at Session.applyCodeActionCommand (/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/extensions/node_modules/typescript/lib/tsserver.js:179894:50)
    at Session.handlers.ts.Map.ts.getEntries._a.<computed> (/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/extensions/node_modules/typescript/lib/tsserver.js:178253:61)
    at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/extensions/node_modules/typescript/lib/tsserver.js:180174:96
    at Session.executeWithRequestId (/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/extensions/node_modules/typescript/lib/tsserver.js:180165:28)
    at Session.executeCommand (/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/extensions/node_modules/typescript/lib/tsserver.js:180174:41)
    at Session.onMessage (/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/extensions/node_modules/typescript/lib/tsserver.js:180202:35)
    at process.<anonymous> (/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/extensions/node_modules/typescript/lib/tsserver.js:184368:31)
    at process.emit (node:events:526:28)
    at emit (node:internal/child_process:938:14)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:84:21)
```

My VS Code:

```
Version: 1.72.2
Commit: d045a5eda657f4d7b676dedbfa7aab8207f8a075
Date: 2022-10-12T22:16:30.254Z (1 wk ago)
Electron: 19.0.17
Chromium: 102.0.5005.167
Node.js: 16.14.2
V8: 10.2.154.15-electron.0
OS: Darwin x64 21.6.0
Sandboxed: No
```